# Button to display html code that is hidden?

Tags: java, html, web, button

I am wondering if it is possible for once a user clicks on a button on a html/jsp website that something appears on the same page? So essentially some text is hidden until the button is click and then it will appear? I'm new to web dev so am unsure if this is even possible, thanks

Comment: take a look at jquery hide and show function

Comment: Sure this is possible. Either reload the page (i.e. send some information to the server and rerender the page as needed) or change the DOM via JavaScript. There are plenty of tutorials on both approaches out there.

Comment: Thats a basic requirement. Have a look at CSS and the display-attribute. You can set that with any JS-framework or manually.

Answer (score 1):

Button to display html code that is hidden.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <button id="showContent" >
Click Me to Show Content
</button>
<button id="hideContent" style="display:none" >
Click Me to Hide Content
</button>
    <div id="hiddenId" style="display:none">Welcome Dear!</div>
</body>
<script >

$("#showContent").click(function(){
    $("#hideContent").show();
    $("#showContent").hide();

$("#hiddenId").show();
});
$("#hideContent").click(function(){
    $("#showContent").show();
    $("#hideContent").hide();
$('#hiddenId').hide();
});
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript to toggle the `display` style attribute of an element:

```js
const display = () => document.querySelector('#elt').style.display = 'block';
const hide = () => document.querySelector('#elt').style.display = 'none';
```

```html
<button onclick="display()">Display</button>
<button onclick="hide()">Hide</button>
<div id="elt">Hello world</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery to dynamically show and hide elements on your page. I would recommend looking at it
https://jsfiddle.net/rxnfwzoj/1/
here is a small example of the `.hide()` and `.show()` function

Comment: Using the whole jQuery just for the sake of display/hide is an overkill in my opinion. Check out [VanillaJS](http://vanilla-js.com/) ;)

Comment: jep, totally is. could be one with just pure js as seen in the awnser from nino but i just love jquery haha but you are right